# How to pass std::map as a default constructor parameter in c++ class function

Tags: c++, clang, stdmap

I have a problem when attempting to use `std::map` in clang-3.3 and clang-3.0 on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
#if 0 //clang compiles ok
    typedef std::map<std::string,std::string> MapKeyValue_t;
    void PrintMap(const MapKeyValue_t &my_map 
        = MapKeyValue_t())
#else // clang compiles fail
    void PrintMap(const std::map<std::string,std::string> &my_map 
    = std::map<std::string,std::string>())
#endif
{
    std::map<std::string,std::string>::const_iterator it;
    for (it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.PrintMap();
    return 0;
}
```

However, while the code compiles in both `g++` and `clang` I keep getting these errors as output:

```
test.cpp:14:36: error: expected ')'
        = std::map<std::string,std::string>())
                                          ^
test.cpp:13:15: note: to match this '('
        void PrintMap(const std::map<std::string,std::string> &my_map 
                     ^
test.cpp:14:24: error: expected '>'
        = std::map<std::string,std::string>())
                              ^
test.cpp:28:13: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
        a.PrintMap();
        ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
test.cpp:13:2: note: 'PrintMap' declared here
        void PrintMap(const std::map<std::string,std::string> &my_map 
        ^
3 errors generated.
```

The closest thing I could find that matches my problem is this topic: [How to pass std::map as a default constructor parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128776/how-to-pass-stdmap-as-a-default-constructor-parameter)

**But, I have no idea what's wrong.** Hopefully, someone can shed some light on this, please.

Update:

```
void PrintMap(const std::map<std::string,std::string> &my_map 
        = (std::map<std::string,std::string>()))
```

is ok. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13657 - suggested workaround is to put parens around the default argument, which does make it compile here.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled and run it successfully in vs2012.
So I think it's compilers problem.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's clang bug, and I'm also waiting clang forks' help.

Comment: why do you use gcc? i never saw clang before!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JanDoggen While I agree that this answer is very low quality it actually is an answer ("it's a compiler bug").

Comment: @BlackMamba why not using gcc? why do you use vs2012? Is it free? Is it good? clang is one of, if not the, best c++11 compilers. This seems a rare glitch.

Comment: @Walter vs2012 Express is free, and is very good in many ways, not so good in some others. It's a very sophisticated IDE, so it really isn't comparable to gcc. Of course it's useless if you're not running Windows ... a possibility that BlackMamba seems not to have considered, and perhaps is not even aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The other posters are correct, I think this is an instance of [Bug 13657](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13657) which should be fixed in Clang 3.4.

As mentioned in the bug report and the [C++ Standard Core Language Active Issues](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#325) page linked from there (and as you mentioned in your update), you can work around the issue by adding parentheses to the default value as follows:

```
void PrintMap(const std::map<std::string,std::string> &my_map 
    = (std::map<std::string,std::string>()))
```